# Golang - How can I remove indirect dependencies?

Tags: go

As the title states I need to remove an indirect dependency in my project. I am fairly new at Go as well as the project I am working on, so I am not quite sure how to approach it. The dependency in question is `github.com/lib/pq`

When I run `go mod why -m github.com/lib/pq` this is what I am given:

```
foo.com/my/project/is/here
github.com/jmoiron/sqlx
github.com/jmoiron/sqlx.test
github.com/lib/pq
```

I don't know where to start after this...do I need to completely remove `github.com/jmoiron/sqlx` from my project? My initial thought is yes since `lib/pq` is a dependency and I can't go changing `sqlx`.

Comment: Run `go mod tidy` to remove unneeded deps. If something is kept after this in `go.mod`, that is needed.

Comment: @icza correct, that is where I am at now. I have removed all the direct dependencies of ```lib/pq``` and ran ```go mod tidy``` which is where I discovered the indirect dependencies. This is for work and I am required to rid the project of any dependencies of ```lib/pq```, direct or indirect...so it sounds like the only option may be to rip out sqlx and find something else to implement?

Comment: Indirect dependencies are still required to build the project. If you must remove that dependency entirely, then of course you will also need to remove what is importing that dependency.